# DC Term in Python FFT - Amplitude of Constant Term

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing, fft

I've created an FFT class/object that takes signal stored in a 2D array and produces the subsequent FFT of its input, before printing it to a matplotlib graph.

After a great deal of reading, I appreciate that due to windowing, the need to have an ideally 2^x number of points and an integer number of cycles in the data set, that the amplitude of the peaks will never be 100% accurate (but will be approximately right).

However, when I add a DC offset to the signal, for some reason, the 0 Hz frequency has a peak that is always exactly double the actual DC/constant offset! For example, if I add 2 to a sine wave of x Hz, I get a peak at x Hz on the FFT, and a peak of 4 at 0.

Why is this - and can I correct this?

Thanks!

The code I am using is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class FFT:
    def __init__(self, time, signal, buff=1, scaling=2, centre=False): 
        self.signal = signal
        self.buff = buff
        self.time = time
        self.scaling = scaling
        self.centre = centre
        if (centre):
            self.scaling = 1
    def fft(self):
        self.Y = np.fft.fft(self.signal, self.buff * len(self.signal))  # Do fft on signal and store
        if (self.centre is True):
            self.Y = np.fft.fftshift(self.Y)  # centre 0 frequency in centre
        self.__graph__()
    def __graph__(self):
        self.N = len(self.Y) / self.scaling  # get FFT length (halved to avoid reflection)
        print (self.N)
        self.fa = 1 / (self.time[1] - self.time[0])  # get time interval & sampling frequency of FFT
        if (self.centre is True):
        self.t_axis = np.linspace(-self.fa / 2 * self.scaling, self.fa / 2 * self.scaling, self.N, endpoint=True)  # create x axis vector from 0 to nyquist freq. (fa/2) with N values
        else:
            self.t_axis = np.linspace(0, self.fa / self.scaling, self.N, endpoint=True)  # create x axis vector from 0 to nyquist freq. (fa/2) with N values
    def show(self, absolute=True):

        if absolute:
            plt.plot(self.t_axis, ((2.0) * self.buff / (self.N * (self.scaling))) * np.abs(self.Y[0:self.N]))
        else:
            plt.plot(self.t_axis, ((2.0) * self.buff / (self.Ns * (self.scaling))) * self.Y[0:self.N])  # multiply y axis by 2/N to get actual values
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()

def sineExample(start=0, dur=128, samples=16384):    
    t = np.linspace(start, dur + start, samples, True)
    print(t)
    f = 10.0  # Frequency in Hz
    A = 10.0  # Amplitude in Unit
    retarr = np.zeros(len(t))    
    retarr = np.column_stack((t, retarr))
    for row in range(len(retarr)):
        retarr[row][1] = A * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * retarr[row][0]) + 2 # Signal  
    print(retarr)
    return retarr

hTArray = sineExample()
# plt.plot(hTArray[:,0], hTArray[:,1])
# plt.grid()
# plt.show()

myFFT = FFT(hTArray[:, 0], hTArray[:, 1], scaling=2,centre=False)
myFFT.fft()
myFFT.show()
```

Comment: What's wrong with simply doing `np.fft.fft(hTArray[:, 1])` for your signal? I would say that your factor `((2.0) * self.buff / (self.N * (self.scaling))) ` must be wrong if you are not getting the correct amplitude of the DC component.

Comment: The factor affects all terms equally - and yet it is only the DC/0 Hz term that is consistently double its true value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the opposite.  All the other frequencies in a full complex FFT result of strictly real data are split into 2 result bins and mirrored as complex conjugated, thus half a pure sinusoids amplitude when scaled by 1/N, except the DC component and N/2 cosine component, which are not split into 2 FFT results, and thus not halved.

Comment: How could I go about correcting this error? Would using the python rfft avoid this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Divide all your results by 2.  Than double the mirrored results by adding the two complex conjugate halves back together (same as multiplying by 2).  The DC component isn't mirrored (or some say mirrored but already added to itself), so doesn't need the extra multiply by 2.